# How can I determine what type of logic structure this circuit represents?

Tags: circuit-analysis, digital-logic, boolean-algebra, function

I have the following circuit:

[image]

How can I determine which one of the following functions it represents:

1. F = (AB+CD)'
2. F = ((A+B)(C+D))'
3. F = AB+CD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can determine the functionality by analysing which transistors are controlled by which inputs.

Make a list of which are turned on or off when a given input is high and low.

Then make a list of which transistors need to be turned on in order for the output to be high or low.

Compare the two and you'll be able to build a Karnaugh map for the circuit.

From the Karnaugh map, you can get the SOP terms, and simplify them using boolean algebra. This will give you the answer which is indeed one of those three options.

Comment: I tried that, but I apparently I have a mistake somewhere because I get the wrong answer. Or maybe there is a mistake in the solutions manual. Could you please tell me which option is correct?

Comment: @AliMustafa EE.SE is not a homework answering service. If you want us to give you further pointers, show your workings.

Comment: @AliMustafa I can tell you that one of those three options is indeed correct.

Comment: I will add a photo of my attempt at a solution by hand, but could you just tell me if (3) is the correct one? If it is, then my solution is correct and I don't need any more feedback

Comment: @AliMustafa What happens when A is high and B is high in that circuit? Is F high or low?

Comment: F should be low. I messed up the negations, so I was pretty close but the right answer is (1). Your method worked, so thank you for that.

Comment: @AliMustafa Correct.